# How (and why?) do memory editors work

Tags: memory-editing

Memory editors such as Cheat Engine are able to read the memory of other processes and modify it.

How do they do it?(a code snippet would be interesting!) A process does typically not have the ability to access the memory of another one, the only cases that I've heard of are in sub-processes/threading, but memory editors are typically not related to the target process in any way.

Why do they work? In what scenario is this ability useful aside from using it to hack other processes, why wouldn't the operating system simply disallow unrelated processes from reading the memory of each other?

Comment: The operating system works for the administrator, not the reverse.

Comment: `"A process does typically not have the ability to access the memory of another one"` - Why not?  You can write directly to memory addresses any time you like.  `"Why do they work?"` - By modifying the runtime values and instructions of other processes.  For example, if a running game has your "score" stored at a memory address, you can modify the value at that memory address to change your "score".

Comment: It has been a while since I learned operating systems, but if I remember correctly aren't all the "real" memory addresses hidden behind the virtual memory addresses and attempting to read/write from anything that is not within the virtual memory addresses results in segfault?

Comment: @David: Actually, no, you can't just write to the memory of another process. Your program must ask the OS to write to the memory of another process. The OS _can_ do it, because it's in charge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, the function typically used to alter the memory of another process is called WriteProcessMemory:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory

If you search the [Cheat Engine source code](https://github.com/cheat-engine/cheat-engine) for WriteProcessMemory you can find it both in their Pascal code and the C kernel code. It needs PROCESS_VM_WRITE and PROCESS_VM_OPERATION access to the process which basically means you need to run Cheat Engine as admin.

WriteProcessMemory is used any time you want to alter the runtime behavior of another process. There are legitimate uses, such as with Cheat Engine or [ModOrganizer](https://github.com/TanninOne/modorganizer/), and of course lots of illegitimate ones. It's worth mentioning that anti-virus software is typically trained to look for this API call (among others) so unless your application has been whitelisted it might get flagged because of it.

Comment: The typical legitimate use is a debugger, which needs to change the memory of the process being debugged.

Answer (score 2):

Operating systems typically expose system calls that allow a userspace program to inspect a target process's memory using said system calls.

For instance, the linux kernel supports the `ptrace` system call. This system call is primarily used by the well known debugger `gdb` and by popular system call tracing utilities such as `strace`.

The ptrace system call allows for the inspection of memory contents of the target process, code injection, register manipulation and much more. I would suggest [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6100) as a resource if you are interested in learning more.

On Linux, you can either run a binary from within gdb, or attach to a process. In case of the latter, you need elevated privileges. There are other protections that try to limit what you can do with ptrace, such as the one mentioned [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#ptrace_scope).

On Windows you can achieve the same effect by using the following functions in order : OpenProcess, GetProcAddress, VirtualAllocEx, WriteProcessMemory and CreateRemoteThread. I would suggest [this](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/using-createremotethread-for-dll-injection-on-windows/#gref) as a resource if you are interested in knowing more. You might need elevated privileges to do this on newer Windows versions.