# how do I use tcc to modify code while it's running?

Tags: tcc

in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tl40xidKF-4) at about 8:05 the speaker explains he's using tcc and that allows him to change and compile code while it is already running, as long as the changes aren't too big; I imagine this isn't a very safe way to work in terms of potential crashes, but it seems useful to fine-tune variables and other things like that.
I'm interested in this potential feature, but I can find no reference of it anywhere else online (I've tried loking it up with different keyword combinations but with no related results). What can I do?

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Are you looking for help installing TCC? [This](https://web.stanford.edu/~engler/tickc.pdf) is the only reference I could find to the software you seem to be talking about. I highly doubt it is easily available anywhere, given how hard it was to find anything about it.

Comment: @Awesomepotato29 I already installed tcc, that's not a problem. I was curious about this live-program-editing functionality, and from the way the video presented that I thought this was a feature of tcc and not some other software. Basically I'm interested in how to achieve that effect, so thanks for the pdf (if I can do it with tcc that's great because I already have it, but I'll consider other options too). do you have advice on what tags I should add or what edits I should make to be clearer?

Comment: Is tcc not just a memory-editing program with some special functionality to allow for code insertion? There are loads of explanations as to how something like this works. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006188/how-and-why-do-memory-editors-work) is another post regarding memory editing during runtime.

Comment: @Awesomepotato29 afaik tcc is a c compiler with no memory-editing functionality of its own, but searching for "dynamic" in the docs I found libtcc, which seems to be a library that's related to what I want to do; I'll take a look at that and see if it's what it seems.

Comment: Hang on, what? Based on your question I assumed that a C compiler was not what you were looking for. And 'C seems to be something along the lines of what the original video was talking about.

Comment: @Awesomepotato29 tcc is a "Tiny C Compiler"; the video says "One of the neat things about these puzzles that I'm doing is that I'm using TCC, so I can actually manipulate the puzzle while I'm playing the game." so I assumed that tcc wasn't just a compiler; however from a closer inspection of the docs it looks like it is? So I'm not sure how the original functionality was achieved. Looking at libtcc it looks like it's a library that contains the functionality of tcc, so by including it you can more or less manipulate the compiled program while it's running? this is a bit confusing.

Comment: Oh, so apparently the speaker was referring to Tiny C Compiler all along. Now I have the same question as you. How would you go about doing something like this?

Comment: @Awesomepotato29 I'll keep you updated then, so far it looks like you need to create a program that checks the source file of your actual program every once in a while, and uses libtcc to re-compile it if it's changed; I might be misunderstanding this though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I was looking for: [this page](https://www.developing-stuff.com/how-to-compile-run-c-code-at-runtime-or-how-to-use-c-as-a-scripting-language/) explains that tcc is so tiny it can be included as a library in c programs; this means that you can create a sort of "manager" program that loads the source files for your actual program and compiles+runs them, then it starts to check for updates in the source and updates code on the fly.

Comment: You can also do this in a normal program, if you split it into both a host and a library.

And then, reload the library every time it changes.

Handmade Hero includes an example:
6m15s
https://guide.handmadehero.org/code/day021/